# used package Secure storage flutter but when read null return for me

Tags: flutter, security

I used this pakage in my app ,but when I open the app again ,I have to login again.this code i wrote,I would appreciate it if it could be checked. I read document but not solve this problem ,

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:nona/back/accounting/abstracts/accounting_repo_abstract.dart';
import 'package:nona/back/global_constants.dart';

import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';


class UserStoredData {

  late DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo; // = DeviceInfoPlugin();

  static const PREFERENCE_NAME = "userPreferences";

  static const REGISTER_STATE = "registerState";

  // static const USER_NAME = "userName";
  static const DEVICE_ID = "deviceId";
  static const UNIQUE_ID = "uniqueId";
  static const USER_TOKEN = "userToken";
  static const USER_PHONE = "userPhone";
  static const USER_LAST_ATTEMPT_TIME = "userLastAttemptTime";

  static const ACTIVE_USER = "activeUser";


  final _secureStorage = const FlutterSecureStorage();

  AndroidOptions _getAndroidOptions() => const AndroidOptions(
    encryptedSharedPreferences: true,
  );



  UserStoredData({ required this.deviceInfo});

Future<void>setValue(String name, dynamic value) async {

 // final value = json.encode(name);
    await _secureStorage.write(key: name,value:  value.toString());

    

  }
  Future<int?> readIntValue<T>(String name) async {

    var readData1  =
    await _secureStorage.read(key: name,aOptions: _getAndroidOptions());
   _secureStorage.containsKey(key: name);
    var readData  = await _secureStorage.read(key: name,aOptions: _getAndroidOptions());
    print("--------nn----------------->$readData");
    return  Future.value(int.parse(readData ?? "0"));

    //  var val = _preferences.getInt(name, isEncrypted:  true) ;
    //  print("----nn-->$val");
   //   return val;
    }

   Future<String?> readStringValue<T>(String name) async {

     var readData =
     await _secureStorage.read(key: name,aOptions: _getAndroidOptions());
     print("----nn-->$readData");
     return readData;
   //  var val = _preferences.getString(name, isEncrypted:  true) ;

   //  return val;
   }

  setRegisterState(RegisterState registerState) {
    setValue(REGISTER_STATE, registerState.index);
  }

  Future<RegisterState> getRegisterState() async {
    var state = await readIntValue<int?>(REGISTER_STATE);
    return RegisterState.values[state ?? 0];
  }

  setActiveUser(int userID) {
    setValue(ACTIVE_USER, userID);
  }

  Future<int?> getActiveUser() async {
    return readIntValue<int?>(ACTIVE_USER);
  }

// setUsername(String username) {
//   setValue(USER_NAME, username);
// }
//
// String getUsername() {
//   return readValue<String?>(USER_NAME) ?? "";
// }
//
// setUserPass(String password) {
//   setValue(USER_PASSWORD, password);
// }
//
// String getUserPass() {
//   return readValue<String?>(USER_PASSWORD) ?? "";
// }

  setDeviceID(String deviceID) {
    setValue(DEVICE_ID, deviceID);
  }

  Future<String?> getDeviceID() async {
    return readStringValue<String?>(DEVICE_ID);
  }

  setUserPhone(String userPhone) {
    setValue(USER_PHONE, userPhone);
  }

  Future<String?> getUserPhone() async {
    return readStringValue<String?>(USER_PHONE);
  }

  setUserLastAttemptTime(int lastAttemptTime) {
    setValue(USER_LAST_ATTEMPT_TIME, lastAttemptTime);
  }

  Future<int> getUserLastAttemptTime() async {
    var value = await readIntValue<int>(USER_LAST_ATTEMPT_TIME);
    if (value == null) {
      return Future.value(1);
    } else {
      return Future.value(value);
    }
  }

  setUserToken(String userToken) {
    setValue(USER_TOKEN, userToken);
  }

  Future<String?> getUserToken() async {
    return readStringValue<String?>(USER_TOKEN);
  }

  _setDeviceUniqueID(String deviceID) {
    setValue(UNIQUE_ID, deviceID);
  }

  Future<String?> getDeviceUniqueID() async {
    var uID = await readStringValue<String?>(UNIQUE_ID);
    if (uID == null) {
      uID = await findDeviceUniqueID(deviceInfo);
      _setDeviceUniqueID(uID!);
    }
    return uID;
  }


}
```

and now this error : Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1). This is the error Code:

Comment: Please [edit] and try to clarify your problem.  When and where is the exception occurring? What is the error code?